# Rotate text button in flex?

Tags: css

I would be grateful for advice about how to rotate a button in a flex context. I have a flex container with a "row" direction (that is, the three content items are arranged from left to right in a row), and the leftmost content item is a `<div>` that contains just a `<button>` with a few words of text in it. I want that `<div>` to be rendered vertically (so that the text reads from bottom to top), to hug the left edge of the container, and to be just the width of its one line of text.

The sample at https://jsfiddle.net/djbpitt/gth3nck9/74/ works as I need it to in Firefox 89, but in Chrome 90 (and Safari 14.1.1) the button is not rotated. caniuse.com tells me that vendor prefixes should not be required for CSS `transform: rotate()` or `writing-mode: vertical-lr;`, and adding a `-webkit` prefix doesn't seem to help anyway.

I would be grateful if someone could please advise me about how I can obtain the behavior I need in the versions of Firefox, Chrome, and Safari mentioned above (which are the latest versions as I write this). I would prefer a pure HTML/CSS (that is, no JavaScript) solution. Thank you!

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
body > * {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100vh;
}
body > section {
    flex: auto;
}
div#button {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 1em;
    border: none;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
button {
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
    padding: 3px;
}
button > span {
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    width: 1em;
    margin: 3px;
}
nav {
    flex: 0 0 20em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    border-right: 1px gray solid;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="button">
      <button><span>Rotate me!</span></button>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>section</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dignissim tristique est, et facilisis urna aliquet et. Vivamus porta laoreet mi non cursus. Integer volutpat tortor lectus, interdum gravida libero interdum ac. Curabitur malesuada cursus laoreet. Donec nec varius est, ac venenatis velit. Vivamus ac ipsum et nibh dictum dignissim. Fusce eget turpis in sem rutrum congue. Donec vitae sollicitudin nunc, elementum porta tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque convallis quam leo, pretium fermentum ante imperdiet sit amet. Quisque egestas risus vitae ante fermentum tincidunt. Sed consectetur efficitur tempus. Nunc tincidunt nunc sed semper accumsan. Ut eu tortor scelerisque, aliquet leo eget, ullamcorper dolor.</p>
    <p>Duis non nisi vitae felis ultricies dapibus pulvinar quis ex. Nullam imperdiet, risus sed pharetra aliquam, mi nulla condimentum purus, tincidunt hendrerit ex metus vitae nisl. Nullam venenatis turpis libero, a bibendum elit venenatis ut. Aenean et orci ac metus pretium pellentesque. Phasellus sed faucibus est. Aenean a dui non augue aliquet sagittis quis at ex. Vestibulum lorem lectus, sodales efficitur lacinia id, iaculis id ante. Fusce aliquam erat libero, a ultrices dolor volutpat et. Vivamus at euismod nisl. Donec hendrerit non lacus vel mollis.</p>
    <p>Phasellus gravida non nisi quis vehicula. Curabitur sagittis nec nulla eget sollicitudin. Mauris sit amet mattis ligula. Nulla pretium posuere diam vitae tempor. Aenean consequat ligula luctus quam vestibulum, vel rhoncus turpis laoreet. Etiam nec aliquam ipsum, ut tristique lorem. In nec auctor arcu. Proin sed finibus ligula. Sed scelerisque lorem ligula. Nam quis quam vehicula, hendrerit nibh nec, rhoncus elit. Praesent porttitor, tellus nec aliquam sollicitudin, justo orci sagittis nisl, non imperdiet ligula mauris sit amet eros. In dignissim placerat laoreet. Aenean ipsum lorem, aliquet id arcu id, rhoncus porta justo. Integer egestas mauris quam, eget placerat metus sagittis eget. Aenean volutpat eleifend nisi eget interdum.</p>
<p>
Vestibulum in ante lectus. Mauris luctus imperdiet facilisis. Nunc sagittis velit lacus, eget gravida arcu efficitur vitae. Sed sodales felis elit, eget volutpat dui congue sit amet. Fusce mi velit, cursus volutpat dapibus in, auctor id dolor. Maecenas convallis nisl justo. Cras sollicitudin tellus nec dui dictum finibus. Fusce nec feugiat metus. Aliquam sit amet congue nulla. Sed cursus fringilla sapien et malesuada. Duis aliquet, nunc eget consectetur fringilla, felis lectus ultrices mi, id maximus justo mauris a mi.</p>
<p>
Vivamus ac est vitae nulla dignissim posuere ac id arcu. Duis sed tortor pretium, tempus orci vel, efficitur ex. Quisque aliquet enim mattis odio tincidunt lacinia. Vestibulum blandit congue neque ac bibendum. Proin at consequat tortor, id malesuada dolor. Integer interdum purus sit amet leo venenatis, gravida porttitor ipsum eleifend. Donec venenatis maximus faucibus. Duis et magna vitae arcu malesuada sodales.</p>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: would you mind copy your snippet from jsfiddle here and create a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)?

Comment: Stack snippet (of working solution, see my response below) added in response to request by lastr2d2.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to lie with Chrome/Edge settings for button. They have for example amongst other things:

```
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
```

So this snippet gives up trying to style a button and replaces it with a div. Obviously you'll want to style that as you wish:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

body>* {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

div#button {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 1em;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  border: none;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

#button div {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

nav {
  flex: 0 0 20em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  border-right: 1px gray solid;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
  <div>Rotate me!</div>
</div>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>section</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dignissim tristique est, et facilisis urna aliquet et. Vivamus porta laoreet mi non cursus. Integer volutpat tortor lectus, interdum gravida libero interdum ac. Curabitur malesuada cursus
    laoreet. Donec nec varius est, ac venenatis velit. Vivamus ac ipsum et nibh dictum dignissim. Fusce eget turpis in sem rutrum congue. Donec vitae sollicitudin nunc, elementum porta tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
    nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque convallis quam leo, pretium fermentum ante imperdiet sit amet. Quisque egestas risus vitae ante fermentum tincidunt. Sed consectetur efficitur tempus. Nunc tincidunt nunc sed semper accumsan. Ut eu tortor
    scelerisque, aliquet leo eget, ullamcorper dolor.</p>
  <p>Duis non nisi vitae felis ultricies dapibus pulvinar quis ex. Nullam imperdiet, risus sed pharetra aliquam, mi nulla condimentum purus, tincidunt hendrerit ex metus vitae nisl. Nullam venenatis turpis libero, a bibendum elit venenatis ut. Aenean et
    orci ac metus pretium pellentesque. Phasellus sed faucibus est. Aenean a dui non augue aliquet sagittis quis at ex. Vestibulum lorem lectus, sodales efficitur lacinia id, iaculis id ante. Fusce aliquam erat libero, a ultrices dolor volutpat et. Vivamus
    at euismod nisl. Donec hendrerit non lacus vel mollis.</p>
  <p>Phasellus gravida non nisi quis vehicula. Curabitur sagittis nec nulla eget sollicitudin. Mauris sit amet mattis ligula. Nulla pretium posuere diam vitae tempor. Aenean consequat ligula luctus quam vestibulum, vel rhoncus turpis laoreet. Etiam nec aliquam
    ipsum, ut tristique lorem. In nec auctor arcu. Proin sed finibus ligula. Sed scelerisque lorem ligula. Nam quis quam vehicula, hendrerit nibh nec, rhoncus elit. Praesent porttitor, tellus nec aliquam sollicitudin, justo orci sagittis nisl, non imperdiet
    ligula mauris sit amet eros. In dignissim placerat laoreet. Aenean ipsum lorem, aliquet id arcu id, rhoncus porta justo. Integer egestas mauris quam, eget placerat metus sagittis eget. Aenean volutpat eleifend nisi eget interdum.</p>
  <p>
    Vestibulum in ante lectus. Mauris luctus imperdiet facilisis. Nunc sagittis velit lacus, eget gravida arcu efficitur vitae. Sed sodales felis elit, eget volutpat dui congue sit amet. Fusce mi velit, cursus volutpat dapibus in, auctor id dolor. Maecenas
    convallis nisl justo. Cras sollicitudin tellus nec dui dictum finibus. Fusce nec feugiat metus. Aliquam sit amet congue nulla. Sed cursus fringilla sapien et malesuada. Duis aliquet, nunc eget consectetur fringilla, felis lectus ultrices mi, id maximus
    justo mauris a mi.</p>
  <p>
    Vivamus ac est vitae nulla dignissim posuere ac id arcu. Duis sed tortor pretium, tempus orci vel, efficitur ex. Quisque aliquet enim mattis odio tincidunt lacinia. Vestibulum blandit congue neque ac bibendum. Proin at consequat tortor, id malesuada dolor.
    Integer interdum purus sit amet leo venenatis, gravida porttitor ipsum eleifend. Donec venenatis maximus faucibus. Duis et magna vitae arcu malesuada sodales.</p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

OP here. Thank you, A Haworth, for the pointer to the `!important` user agent setting for `writing-mode` in Webkit. I knew that browsers had default styling, of course, but I didn't realize that some of that styling apparently could not be overridden with user specifications.

Your insight led me to give up on changing the `writing-mode` value for the `<button>`, as you suggest, and I approached the task by wrapping a `<span>` around the text inside my `<button>` and specifying the `writing-mode` for the `<span>`. The new version is at https://jsfiddle.net/djbpitt/gth3nck9/86/. HTML and CSS are copied below:

```html
<div id="button">
  <button>
    <span>Rotate me!</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I had to do some additional fiddling with the CSS to get the rendering I wanted:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
body > * {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100vh;
}
body > section {
    flex: auto;
}
div#button {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 1em;
    border: none;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
button {
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
    padding: 3px;
}
button > span {
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    width: 1em;
    margin: 3px;
}
nav {
    flex: 0 0 20em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    border-right: 1px gray solid;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```